# How to redirect to parent object after child record creation

Tags: salesforce, parent-child, lightning

Looking for a standard ways to redirect to parent Object after Child record creation on salesforce Lightning by using URL's on Master Object List view button

Could not find a way to redirect to parent Object on Child creation